# two laravel installations session destroy

Tags: php, session, laravel

I have two laravel 4 installations in my htdocs folder.
`htdocs/laravel1` and `htdocs/laravel2`.
Both have different databases and also a different key in `app/config/app.php`

Both installations have the driver database for sessions in the config.
I want to start both installations with the `artisan serve` command.
the first laravel is started with artisan serve on port 8000.
the second laravel is started with `artisan serve --port=4000`

**The problem:**
When I login in laravel1, and then login into laravel2, my Session in laravel1 is away ... why is this happen? as I say, they are in different databases, and they have a different key in the config file. How can I avoid this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have use different session cookie name for each installation, as they are on the same domain. You should be able to set it in `app/config/session.php`.